# Is there a way to return single element from array stored as regular Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I use regular `observable` (not `observableArray`), which keeps an array of elements, something like this:

```
public arrayOfItems: IArrayItem[];
public arrayOfItems$: BehaviorSubject<IArrayItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject<IArrayItem[]>(null);

public setArrayOfItems(arrayOfItems: IArrayItem[]): void {
  this.arrayOfItems = arrayOfItems;
  this.arrayOfItems$.next(arrayOfItems);
}

public getArrayOfItems(): Observable<IArrayItem[]> {
  return this.arrayOfItems$.asObservable();
}
```

And I'd like to implement a `getSingleItemFromArray` method, which should return a single element from `arrayOfItems$` and I'd like to get it `asObservable` too. Something like this (pseudocode):

```
public getSingleItemFromArray(): Observable<IArrayItem> {
  return this.arrayOfItems$.find(item => item.condition).asObservable();
}
```

If it is possible, please, point me to the right direction to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `arrayOfItems$` is an instance of `BehaviorSubject` you can use one of the following depending on your use-case:

1. If you want to just replay the single value you can use:

   ```
   return arrayOfItems$.take(1)
   ```

   This emits the value cached by the `BehaviorSubject` and ends the chain with a proper `complete` notification thanks to `take(1)`.

   Note that you don't have to use `asObservable` because each operator returns an Observable.
2. You can actually get the value stored inside `BehaviorSubject` and return in wrapped with an Observable:

   ```
   const val = arrayOfItems$.getValue();
   return Observable.of(val);
   ```

I'd personally use the first option because it feels more "Rx".

Comment: I can't figure out what is the correct way of using the first method (my fault, I'm sure that it should work), but the second way works perfectly, thanks! Upvote and accept!

Comment: @CommercialSuicide If you're using RxJS 5.5 you need to use `pipe` like `arrayOfItems$.pipe(take(1))`

Answer (score 3):

use `Observable.of` to converts argument to an observable sequence.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

public getSingleItemFromArray(): Observable<IArrayItem> {
   let item: IArrayItem = this.arrayOfItems$.find(item => item.condition);
   return Observable.of(item )
}
```

Comment: I really like @martin answer, but thanks for your answer too, upvote!